CSS: overflow-x: scroll works in Chrome devtools' "device mode" but not otherwise
I'm working on a top navbar in which certain buttons exist within a horizontal fraction of the navbar that can shrink as the window gets narrower, and when that allocated area shrinks, the inner div containing the buttons needs to be able to scroll left and right to allow the user to choose between the buttons.
So the way I have it set up is that there's an outer div set to flex (so it can grow and shrink as the window gets bigger and smaller) and overflow-x: scroll, then the inner div that contains the buttons and is the full width necessary to contain all those buttons.
The problem I'm having is that this dragging works when I use Chrome devtools' "device mode", but it doesn't work otherwise, and I can't figure out why.
Able to drag the inner div in Chrome devtools' "device mode":

Unable to drag the inner div when outside of "device mode":

Interestingly, holding shift and using the scroll wheel does allow me to scroll the div.

Did you try overflow-x: visible?

@NaikJavaid That makes the entire inner div visible, which isn't what I want: https://i.imgur.com/aZYoxke.png I want to be able to drag the inner div left and right to change which part of it is visible in the outer div.

I figured it out: click-and-drag-to-scroll apparently isn't a natively-supported interaction on desktop, so you'll need to use a library to get it working.
You can find an npm package for your JS framework by searching Google for "npm dragscroll".
Here's the plain JS dragscroll.
I'm using Angular, so I went with ngx-drag-scroll.
